# Pandas Read Multiple CSVs & Use Filename in Rows with Single Data Column

Tags: pandas, csv, concatenation

I need to read multiple csv files into a pandas df and keep the unique filename as a column of rows along with the date column and data column. My files look like this:

```
filename: 34.UNITED STATES.COPPER CROSSING.RADIATION.csv
    YYMMDD      HHMM    CC1.SR.AvMetRefSolar
    20180101    100     5.8
    20180101    200     0
    20180101    300     0
    20180101    400     0
    20180101    500     0

filename: 35.UNITED STATES.GALA.RADIATION.csv    
    YYMMDD      HHMM    GA1.SR.AvMetRefSolar
    20180101    100     8
    20180101    200     0.3
    20180101    300     0.7
    20180101    400     1
    20180101    500     1.3
```

I'm using this to define the path + filenames:

```
pathd = r'C:\\Users\\U321103\\'

all_files = glob.glob(pathd + "/*UNITED STATES.*RADIATION.csv")
```

I need the result to look like this:

```
plant_name     data YYMMDD     HHMM
COPPER CROSSING 5.8 20180101    100
COPPER CROSSING 0   20180101    200
COPPER CROSSING 0   20180101    300
COPPER CROSSING 0   20180101    400
COPPER CROSSING 0   20180101    500
GALA            8   20180101    100
GALA            0.3 20180101    200
GALA            0.7 20180101    300
GALA            1   20180101    400
GALA            1.3 20180101    500
```

I have tried several things that with pd.concat with pd_read_csv but cannot get the data to concatenate in rows sequentially by each filename change. your guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404876/pandas-read-multiple-csvs-with-different-data-column-name

Comment: i've simplified the question so it should be more clear. I will delete the other question.

Comment: i've deleted the original question - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works when I create the two csv files on my local machine. Depending on your filename/filepath (f), you may have to play around with the split function to get the right part of the file name. Assumes all filenames and content are the same as well.

```
df_list = []
for f in all_files:
    # print(f.split('.')[2])
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=' \s+', engine='python')
    df['plant_name'] = f.split('.')[2]
    df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]:'data'}, inplace=True)
    df_list.append(df)

df_final = pd.concat(df_list)
df_final

     YYMMDD  HHMM  data       plant_name
0  20180101   100   5.8  COPPER CROSSING
1  20180101   200   0.0  COPPER CROSSING
2  20180101   300   0.0  COPPER CROSSING
3  20180101   400   0.0  COPPER CROSSING
0  20180101   100   8.0             GALA
1  20180101   200   0.3             GALA
2  20180101   300   0.7             GALA
3  20180101   400   1.0             GALA
4  20180101   500   1.3             GALA
```